# Avoid same Woocommerce customer order number set by counting different order type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am setting the woocommerce order number by counting different order type from the database. There are three different types of orders: A, B and C. The final order number is set by counting the numbers of different order type within a date. If two customers place order at the same time, like 12:23:54, it produce same order number. How to avoid this? Thanks in advance for any input.

Order type is stored as order custom field: order_type

Checkout set order number function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'saving_checkout_cf_data');
function saving_checkout_cf_data( $order_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $order_type = $_POST['order_type'];
    $suffix = date("Ymd");
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $date_string = "> '$date'";
    $in = "1";
    if ($order_type=='A'){
        $count_A = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(*) AS THE_COUNT 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
        ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
        WHERE (
        $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_date $date_string
        AND meta_key = 'order_type' 
        AND meta_value = 'A'
        )
        ");
        $final_count_A = sprintf("%03d", $count_A->THE_COUNT + $in);
        $final_id = $order_type . $suffix . $final_count_A;
        update_post_meta( $order_id , 'customer_order_number', sanitize_text_field( $final_id ) );
    } else if ($order_type=='B') {
        $count_B = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(*) AS THE_COUNT 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
        ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
        WHERE (
        $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_date $date_string
        AND meta_key = 'order_type' 
        AND meta_value = 'B'
        )
        ");
        $final_count_B  = sprintf("%03d", $count_B->THE_COUNT + $in);
        $final_id = $order_type . $suffix . $final_count_B;
        update_post_meta( $order_id , 'customer_order_number', sanitize_text_field( $final_id ) );
    } else {
        $count_C = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(*) AS THE_COUNT 
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
        ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
        WHERE (
        $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_date $date_string
        AND meta_key = 'order_type' 
        AND meta_value = 'C'
        )
        ");
        $final_count_C = sprintf("%03d", $count_C->THE_COUNT + $in);
        $final_id = $order_type . $suffix . $final_count_C;
        update_post_meta( $order_id , 'customer_order_number', sanitize_text_field( $final_id ) );
    }
    }
```

Comment: `$order_id` is unique no matter how many people place an order in the same second. Use `$order_id`

Comment: Hello, can you explain more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It doesn't make sense why you are saving `$final_id` and then ignoring the unique integer `$order_id` later on when looking up the orders. But since you are, include it in `$final_id`, e.g. `$final_id = $order_type . $suffix . $final_count_C . "__" . $order_id;`

Comment: I see, thanks for your comment. However the problem is we don't want the actual $order_id.

Comment: Well that's your unequivocal unique id.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am reaching out for help. Thanks.